# Can't update specific fields in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm using the ion_auth for Codeigniter. I send the default values for active, sms_active as 0 and the default values for these fields are 0 but they get inserted as 1 I try to update these fields after the registration is successful but they don't get updated though I get the update success message. They are always 1 how to find ideas to solve this issue.

From the register function in `ion_auth_model`

```
$data = array(
    $this->identity_column   => $identity,
    'password'   => $password,
    'email'      => $email,
    'ip_address' => $ip_address,
    'created_on' => time(),
    'sms_active' => 0,
    'active'     => 0
);
```

In the controller after the registration is successful

```
$updated_data = array(
    'active'     => 0 ,
    'sms_active' => 0
);
$this->ion_auth->update($id, $updated_data);
```

I even tried updating values using Ajax from the view

```
$(function () {
      $.post("<?=base_url()?>users/register/deactivate",{'id':"<?=$id?>"});
});

$q="update users set active = 0, sms_active = 0 where id = '$id'";
$this->db->query($q);
```

Fields are `tinyint(1)` default 0

Answer (score 0):

1. If your table, this "trouble field" set default = 0, and for "the first time", value of that field = 0, better is don't include that field at $data
2. Please check again table and your code script (specially ion_auth)

Comment: Now not sending these values and just set the default values of these fields to 0 but still inserting 1 . This problem happened  suddenly the code was working fine and was inserting 0 now it doesn't without any modifications